# multiple blog layout single solution wordpress plugin

Tags: layout, blogs

I am looking for wordpress plugin that give me capability to design my blog pages with different layouts based on different wordpress categories and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one perfect plugin in WordPress, called [**Blog Designer**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-designer/).

And this plugin is also available with PRO version. That will give you 15+ different and unique blog layouts. Enjoy it!